# how to plot each key of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a dic of list type. like this :

```
{'key': '3d animator',
  'Results': [{'freelance artist': 1}, {'3d artist': 2}]},
 {'key': '3d artist',
  'Results': [{'sous chef': 1},
   {'3d animator': 2},
   {'art director': 1},
   {'artist': 1}]},
 {'key': '3d designer',
  'Results': [{'network administrator': 1}, {'None': 1}]}
```

can I plot a graph for each `key`, and show by hist the frequency of the `values` `('Results)`
? for example for `key= 3d animator`, a hist chart where in the horizontal  axis I have `'freelance artist'` and `3d artist` and in the vertical axis their frequency `1` and `2`?

Comment: Do you mean Histogram by hist and Dictionary by dic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion is to reformat your data:

```
my_list = [{'key': '3d animator',
  'Results': [{'freelance artist': 1}, {'3d artist': 2}]},
 {'key': '3d artist',
  'Results': [{'sous chef': 1},
   {'3d animator': 2},
   {'art director': 1},
   {'artist': 1}]},
 {'key': '3d designer',
  'Results': [{'network administrator': 1}, {'None': 1}]}]
```

Assuming each key in subdict lists is unique:

```
final_dict = {elem["key"]:{k: v for d in elem["Results"] for k, v in d.items()} for elem in my_list}
```

Then plot each value (dict) of the outer dict (dataset):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for k,v in final_dict.items():
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(k)
    plt.bar(list(v.keys()), v.values())
plt.show()
```

This plots a graph for each key of the dataset (if that's your need).

[image: plots]

Comment: double list comprehension (final_dict): for each element of my list take key and as value: merge of each entry of the lists "element["Results"]"

Comment: could you please tell me where in the code you put titles? (`keys`)

Comment: plt.title(k) in the for loop

Comment: is there anyway to sort each graph with respect of the frequency?

Comment: Easiest way is to sort data before plotting, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value